# Identity Id in AWS Cognito changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I established a authentication flow with Facebook Login and AWS Cognito on the client. I need a reference of the user with its facebook id in a dynambodb table and verify that the API call actually has a valid facebook id this facebook id matches the AWS Cognito Id. 
I found a solution in this answer: [AWS Cognito, Lambda, User credentials in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140545/aws-cognito-lambda-user-credentials-in-dynamodb)

But after I login in the Cognito for several times on the same device , I found that there are several different identity id in the console. Like this:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zshg4.png)

I thought the identity id would be unique for a certain device with a certain Facebook id. Do I make some mistake? If the identity id changes, how can I store the data of the Facebook user in dynamoDB?

This is my code:

```
void Start()

    {
        InitCognito ();

    }
    public void InitCognito()
    {
        UnityInitializer.AttachToGameObject (this.gameObject);
        credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials (
            identity_pool_id, // Identity Pool ID
            region // Region
        );

        Debug.Log ("identity_pool_id = " + identity_pool_id + " region = " + region);

        credentials.GetIdentityIdAsync(delegate(AmazonCognitoIdentityResult<string>
            result) {
            if (result.Exception != null) {
                Debug.LogError(result.Exception.ToString());
            }
            string identityId = result.Response;
            Debug.Log("identityId = "+identityId);
            FBInit();
        });



    }



    public void FBInit()
    {
        FB.Init(this.OnInitComplete, this.OnHideUnity);
        Debug.Log( "FB.Init() called with " + FB.AppId);

    }

    public void FBLogin()
    {

        FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email", "user_friends" }, this.HandleResult);

    }


    private void OnInitComplete()
    {
        Debug.Log( "Success - Check log for details");
        Debug.Log("Success Response: OnInitComplete Called\n");
        Debug.Log( string.Format(
            "OnInitCompleteCalled IsLoggedIn='{0}' IsInitialized='{1}'",
            FB.IsLoggedIn,
            FB.IsInitialized));

        if (AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Access token = "+AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.ToString());
        }
        FBLogin ();
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        Debug.Log( "Success - Check log for details");
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Success Response: OnHideUnity Called {0}\n", isGameShown));
        Debug.Log("Is game shown: " + isGameShown);
    }
    protected void HandleResult(IResult result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Null Response\n");

            return;
        }



        // Some platforms return the empty string instead of null.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
        {
            Debug.Log( "Error - Check log for details");
            Debug.Log( "Error Response:\n" + result.Error);
        }
        else if (result.Cancelled)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Cancelled - Check log for details");
            Debug.Log( "Cancelled Response:\n" + result.RawResult);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.RawResult))
        {
            Debug.Log ("Success - Check log for details");
            Debug.Log ("Success Response:\n" + result.RawResult);
            Debug.Log ("Access Token = "+AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken);
            Debug.Log ("Access Token = "+AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString);
            Debug.Log ("Access User Id =" + AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId);
            credentials.AddLogin ("graph.facebook.com", AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString);
            if (credentials.CurrentLoginProviders.Length > 0) {
                Debug.Log (credentials.CurrentLoginProviders[0]);
            }

            Debug.Log (credentials.GetCachedIdentityId());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ( "Empty Response\n");
        }


    }
```

When the InitCognito() method is executed, I get a unAuthorized Identity Id(once I reinstall this app on the same device, the unAuthorized  Identity Id changes). The I can get the Facebook user id and token successfully. After the credentials.AddLogin() method executed, Debug.Log (credentials.GetCachedIdentityId()) shows that the Identity Id is the same as the unAuthorized Identity Id, not a specific id referenced to the Facebook Id. Do I use credentials.AddLogin() in a wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: Click into these identities. Do they have a login linked to them?

Comment: Two of them have linked logins. The "linked logins" field shows "graph.facebook.com" in the first one and "DISABLED us-east-1" in the second one.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have multiple identities showing up is they're unauthenticated. You're making lots of requests without giving the facebook token. Any requests with the facebook token will give you the same authenticated id (the one you mentioned above), but you do have to continue providing that token to get it. Those will map to a unique id, but requests without one will not.

Comment: I think you're right. But sometimes the authenticated id is just the same as the unauthenticated id. Maybe there is some mistake in my code. I have pasted my code in the question. Could you please help me again? Thank you!

Comment: To continue Jeff's explanation, you first get an unauthenticated identity identA. When you provide the FB token and idenA to the service, it links the login to this identity so idenA is now an authenticated identity. Next time, if you do not provide the FB token, you will get a new unauthenticated identity idenB. If you provide the FB token for the same user now, you will get back idenA. If the FB token belongs to a different user, idenB will now be linked to this new user.

Comment: For subsequent Lambda calls, would one pass the FB token again? Or will " providing ".. the FB token and idenA to the [??????] service" return a session token that one sends back to the caller, and expect that the caller will send that token along for future calls?

If this is too n00b, please feel free to point me to something that actually explains this